# How can I add a path to the CSV files created?

Tags: python, pandas

Im splitting a CSV file based on column "ColumnName". How can I make all the CSV files created save into a specified path?

```
  data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\Output.csv')
  for (ColumnName), group in data.groupby(['ColumnName']):
       group.to_csv('{ColumnName}.csv', index=False)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try mode='append' as a parameter of to_csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` takes a string path as input to write to said path.

With your current code `group.to_csv('{ColumnName}.csv', index=False)`, `{ColumnName}` is being interpreted as a normal string. If you wanted variable substition in this case Python has many methods, two would be:

### f-strings - Introduced in Python 3.6

`group.to_csv('{ColumnName}.csv', index=False)`

### str.format

`group.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(ColumnName), index=False)`

---

### Specifying path

Following this. If you're looking to specify more than just the file name, you are able to specify the full file path or the file path relative to the current directory.

### Providing full file path

Full file paths require describing the path from the root context. In windows this would be providing a path such as `f'C:\Users\mycsvfolder\{ColumnName}.csv'`. Providing the full path to `to_csv()` will have the file written there.

**Note** In linux, root context starts at `/`. So for example `/Users/myuser/mycsvfolder/file.csv` would be the full file path.

### Providing a relative file path

Relative file paths take into account the current folder. For example, to instead write to a folder within the current folder you are able to specify `f'mycsvfolder/{ColumnName}.csv'` and the file will be written to the specified folder in the current directory. It's with this method that writing `f'{ColumnName}.csv'` will write a file, but to the current directory as work is relative to the current directory unless otherwise specified.

### Note when writing to folder

You will need to create folders before writing to them in most cases. Some write functions do provide folder creation functionality however.

[Additional material regarding paths, specifically in Python](https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/).

Comment: Not sure if I explained correctly, So the current code is actually working for me but is creating the files in the main folder, I want to all the csv created to be saved in a diferent path. Based on the code you suggested were should I add the new path? Sorry im new to python

Comment: Not a problem! Added some more regarding file paths along with a link to more details. Good luck with your adventures!